# Как сделать flex container, что бы в нём высота всех дочерних элементов не приравнивалась друг к другу?

Tags: flexbox

Хочу сделать 2 колонки со списками. Каждая по 50% от родителя. Внутри будут элементы li, ни будут разной длины по словам, соответственно, будут переноситься вниз.

Как сделать так, что бы соседний li не учитывал высоту другого элемента?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это пример - как сделать так, что бы Four и Six остались прежними по высоте?

А это сам блок с которым я хочу сделать задуманное (если это возможно)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы, что бы пункты шли один за одним.

Comment: Разметка и стили где? С чем работать? От чего отталкиваться? Зачем людям самим набивать текст, если у Вас он уже есть? Дополните вопрос.

Comment: это таблица а не flexbox или grid - давайте как говорится `Кесарю кесарево а слесарю слесарева` а в таблице есть colspan и rowspan

Comment: Вы хотите стандартную раскладку masonry. Поищите это слово и найдёте кучу способов (все на JS). Есть предложение добавить её в гриды, но пока ещё рано это использовать в живой природе

Comment: Либо, если порядок пунктов непринципиален, то обычные колонки https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns